# Problem with SEO - No redirect

Tags: magento2, url, seo

Currently my website works well and my products are having the following URLs

https://baseurl/catalog/product/view/id/19008

However, I bulk changed with the help of a module to a more set friendly URL such as:

```
https://baseurl/name_of_my_product
```

The issue is that I changed 17000 products but the redirect did not occur. I need to save the product one by one for my url to work which is crazy. I indexed the page after changing the url but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Please install this module and run below command to regereate URL**

https://github.com/elgentos/magento2-regenerate-catalog-urls

```
Usage:
 regenerate:product:url [-s|--store="..."] [pids1] ... [pidsN]
 regenerate:category:url [-s]--store="..."] [-r]--root="..."] [cids1] ... [cidsN]
 regenerate:category:path [-s]--store="..."] [-r]--root="..."] [cids1] ... [cidsN]
 regenerate:cms-page:url [-s]--store="..."] [pids1] ... [pidsN]

Arguments:
 pids                  Products (or Pages) to regenerate
 cids                  Categories to regenerate

Options:
 --store (-s)          Use a specific store (store Id, store code or 'all')
 --root (-r)           Regenerate for root category and its children, ignoring cids. 
 --help (-h)           Display this help message

# Regenerate url for all products and the global store
php bin/magento regenerate:product:url

# Regenerate url for products with id (1, 2, 3, 4) for store 1
php bin/magento regenerate:product:url -s1 1 2 3 4

# Regenerate url for all CMS pages
php bin/magento regenerate:cms-page:url -s all

# Regenerate url for root category 4 and its children for store 1
php bin/magento regenerate:category:url -s1 -r4
```

Once you run above command. You must need to run reindex command in magento root.

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Comment: OK. will try it and let you know how it went. many thanks

Comment: It worked great. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Please try once this module**

link : https://github.com/olegkoval/magento2-regenerate_url_rewrites

> Command : php bin/magento ok:urlrewrites:regenerate
> --entity-type=product

Comment: That's great! thanks